# Libgdx Animation Memory Leak

Tags: java, kotlin, libgdx, game-physics, box2d

I am making a game with libgdx.

I am creating new balls in update() at a rate of per 1 second. I added an explosion animation when balls touch a wall.

As you know if I don't remove() or dispose() all animation, after sometimes the game crashes because of memory leak of animations. To avoid this crash I am using Pool classes.

The problem is starting when I try to remove() Explosion actors. I am using Stage class to create animations. The Animation class has constructor which uses `loadAnimationFromSheet()` which has another classes like TextureRegion.

I think when I try to remove the animation, animations are removing but like textureRegions are not removed and this is cause of memory leak.

I am using android profiler to see allocation and memory usage

After 10 minutes the memory is increased.

What can I do to remove all subthings like `loadAnimationFromSheet()` method's Texture or TextureRegion.

To load animation

```
      fun loadAnimationFromFiles(fileNames: Array<String>, frameDuration: Float, loop: Boolean,
                                       textureFilter: TextureFilter = TextureFilter.Linear): Animation<TextureRegion> {
                val textureArray: Array<TextureRegion> = Array()
        
                for (i in 0 until fileNames.size) {
                    val texture = Texture(Gdx.files.internal(fileNames[i]))
                    texture.setFilter(textureFilter, textureFilter)
                    textureArray.add(TextureRegion(texture))
                }
        
                val anim: Animation<TextureRegion> = Animation(frameDuration, textureArray)
        
                if (loop)
                    anim.playMode = Animation.PlayMode.LOOP
                else
                    anim.playMode = Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL
        
                if (animation == null)
                    setAnimation(anim)
        
                return anim
            }
```

setting animation

```
    fun setAnimation(anim: Animation<TextureRegion>) {
            animation = anim
            val tr: TextureRegion = animation!!.getKeyFrame(0.toFloat())
            val w: Float = tr.regionWidth.toFloat()
            val h: Float = tr.regionHeight.toFloat()
            setSize(w, h)
            setOrigin(w/2, h/2)
    
            if (boundaryPolygon == null)
                setBoundaryRectangle()
        }
```

Animation class is called "Explosion"

```
    class Explosion (x: Float, y: Float, s: Stage) : MyActors(x, y, s) {
        init {
            loadAnimationFromSheet("explosion1.png", 6, 6, .03f,true)
        }
    }
```

Pool class of Animation

```
    class ExplosionPool(x: Float, y: Float, s: Stage): Pool<Explosion>() {
        var x = 0f
        var y:Float = 0f
        var s:Stage=s
    
        init {
           this.x=x
            this.y=y
            this.s=s
    
       }
    
    
        override fun newObject(): Explosion {
            return Explosion(x, y, s)
        }
    
    }
```

And lastly my `initialize()` and `update()` methods in GameScreen class.

```
          lateinit var explosions:Array<Explosion>
        
            lateinit var pool: ExplosionPool
        ---------
        ---------
      override fun initialize() {
        -------
        -------
          pool= ExplosionPool(0f,0f,mainStage)
                explosions= Array()
        }
        
      override fun update(dt: Float) {
        -------
        -------
        
        
        
        if (ball.isTouching()==true) {
        val explosion=pool.obtain()
        explosion.centerAtActor(ball)
         explosions.add(drop)
            if(explosions.isAnimationFinished()==true)
                           { explosions.removeValue(drop,true)
                             pool.free(explosions)
                                                  
                          }
       
        
        }
```

When the game launched, the android profiler data
[image]

[image]

After 10 minutes
[image]

[image]

Comment: Don’t load multiple copies of your Texture. Every Explosion instance could be sharing the same Animation instance. Keep track of every instance of every Disposable class, such as Texture, in one place so you can manage what is loaded and unloaded and not load duplicates. Libgdx already provides AssetManager for this purpose.

Comment: Where should I write AssetManager codes in loadAnimationFromFiles() or setAnimation()

Comment: You should instantiate it and store it in a property when the game starts up. Load everything you might use in one place at start up. These various “load” functions should be changed to simply get a Texture reference from the AssetManager.

Comment: I added AssetManager my project. However the game crashes after some minutes again. How can I remove or delete TextureRegion which is in Heap memory.. I added the Android Profiler data last of the question

Comment: After correctly implementing AssetManager, the Texture constructor will not be called from anywhere in your code because the AssetManager handles it. Is this the case now?